# Recommended Ground while testing Laptop with Multimeter?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, power, laptop-repair, ground

I'm about to test my laptop motherboard to make sure a component is receiving power.

All guides point out I need to connect my multimeter to a proper electrical ground.

How do I locate such a ground?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Motherboards are covered in grounds.  Any large metal pad on the motherboard should be a ground.  However, there is an easier place to find a ground:  The metal around any screw hole that mounts the motherboard to the case is a ground.

If you are unsure if a particular pad is a ground, put your multimeter into continuity mode - when it beeps if a circuit is made.  Touch a known ground, such as a screw hole, with one probe and the other to what you are testing for ground.  If it beeps, it is connected to ground.

Comment: I've taken my laptop apart to test for the power so the motherboard is no longer screwed into its case.

Comment: @Merudo the screw holes are still attached to the ground plane.

Comment: That continuity mode has to send a current through the motherboard. If the two points are not directly connected but are connected through a component on the board I'd be a bit concerned. Could the current introduced by the multimeter damage the component? Could you incorrectly conclude the other point is also ground even though the current had to pass through a component on the board?